# Calculating the entropy of an attribute in the ID3 algorithm when a split is perfectly classified

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, decision-theory

I have been reading about the ID3 algorithm recently and it says that the best attribute to be selected for splitting should result in the maximum information gain which can be computed with the help of the entropy.

I have written a simple python program to compute the entropy. It is shown below:

```
def _E(p, n):
    x = (p/(p+n))
    y = (n/(p+n))
    return(-1* (x*math.log2(x)) -1* (y*math.log2(y)))
```

However suppose we have a table consisting of 10 elements as follows:

x = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

y = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Where x is the attribute and y is the class. Here P(0) = 0.8 and P(1) = 0.2. The entropy will be as follows:

Entropy(x) = 0.8*_E(5, 3) + 0.2*_E(2, 0)

However the second split (when x=1) is perfectly classified and this results in a math error since log2(0) is negative infinity. How is the entropy calculated in such cases?

Comment: Even if the titles of these questions is different, you should take note that Shannon entropy for $p=0$ is still well-defined: $0\times\log(0)=0.$ Take the limit as $x$ goes to $0$.